Table/Chart of Tooth Counts for 10:1 Planetary Gear
I'm looking for a chart or table that defines the teeth/tooth count needed in a planetary gear set for a ratio of 10:1.
I'm planning on 3d printing basically a grooved (Lebus), cylinder/drum for a curtain cord winder, and using the cylinder/drum as the ring gear.
The Cord Cylinder/drum is currently 45mm wide 35mm id 52mm od. These dimensions are not a requirement and can be changed to suit the gears.
I'd also like to use the whole inside of the Cord cylinder/drum for all the gears (full width) and use a helical design.
Can anyone link me to some form of chart for the different tooth counts for a 10:1 ratio?
I've read many informative documents S/ (R+S), and R= 2x P+S, also the Ring & Sun have to have an common divisor equal to the number of planets. I'd be very grateful for some advice.
I do also have Fusion 360 (non commercial), but again without knowing what tooth counts to use, I'm at a loss.

Hi Guys,
After taking my Thinking Cap off and ptting it back on many times, I think I may have a tooth count for the 10:1 ratio, but would ask you guys to double check for me:
R = 2 x P + S
Ratio + S / (R + S)
So if I start with a 12 tooth Sun gear;
12 / 0.1 = 120
120 - 12 will calculate the 2 Planets = 108

After taking my Thinking Cap off and putting it back on many times, I think I may have a tooth count that will work for the 10:1 ratio, but would ask you guys to double check for me;
R = 2 x P + S
Ratio = S / (R + S)
If I start with a 12 tooth Sun gear;
12 / 0.1 = 120 (Ring & 2 x Planets)
120 - 12 (R & 2x P - Sun), will calculate the 2 Planets= 108
108 / 2 will calculate the each Planet= 54
So I will have the following:
1x, S @ 12
3x, P @ 54
1x, R @ 108
Then with 3 planets R + S / 3  = which is an integer as needed
Also, all gears are divisible by 3 (Number of planets), as needed
Would my maths be correct?
